# Computing a density of states of Hamiltonian $ H=xp$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, quantization, semiclassical, density-of-states

How could I compute the integral

$$ N(E)~=~ \int dx \int dp~ H(E-xp) $$

the 'Area' inside the Phase space is taken for $ x \ge 0 $ and $ p\ge 0 $?  The result should be

$$ N(E)~=~ \frac{E}{2\pi}\log\frac{E}{2\pi}-\frac{E}{2\pi} ,$$

but I am unable to get it even with cut-offs :(  What am I doing wrong to compute this? Here $H(x)$ is the Heaviside function. At least I would need help to get rid of the term involving the Heaviside function $H(E-xp)$ of the quadrant where both $x$ and $p$ are positive.

Comment: You are basically asking for the area enclosed between the rectangular hyperbola $xp=E$ and its asymptotes (which happen to be the $x$ and $p$ axes). What are the limits on $x$ and $p$?

Comment: Shouldn't $H$ be Hermitian? $xp$ is not!

Comment: H is Hermitian, remember weyl ordering the quantum operator reads $ H= \frac{xp+px}{2}$ and $ x^{T}p^{T}=px$

Answer (score 4):

This question (v1) is discussed near eq. (8) in Ref. 1.

The simplest regularization is to truncate the variables $x\geq\ell_x$ and $p\geq\ell_p$ at cut-offs $\ell_x$ and $\ell_p$, respectively, in such a way that the product $\ell_x \ell_p = h$ is Planck's constant.

In an $(x,p)$ diagram, the truncated area under the hyperbola $p=\frac{E}{x}$  reads in Planck units

$$\begin{align} N(E) ~\approx~&\int_{\ell_x}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{h}\int_{\ell_p}^{\infty}dp~\theta(E-xp)\cr
~=~&\int_{\ell_x}^{\frac{E}{\ell_p}}\frac{dx}{h} \left(\frac{E}{x}-\ell_p\right) \cr
~=~&\frac{1}{h} \left[E\ln x-\ell_p x\right]_{x=\ell_x}^{x=\frac{E}{\ell_p}}\cr
~=~&\frac{E}{h}\left(\ln\frac{E}{h}-1\right)+1,\end{align}$$

where $\theta$ is the Heaviside step function.

References:

1. M.V. Berry and J.P. Keating, *H = xp and the Riemann zeros.*  In J.P. Keating, D.E. Khmelnitski and I.V. Lerner, *Supersymmetry and Trace Formulae: Chaos and Disorder* (1999) 355–367. ([PDF search](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=berry+keating+xp+Riemann+zeros+pdf))